# get odometry from hector_slam

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, laser-scan-matcher, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi ,

i'm trying to improve the odometry of my robot , i'm using wheel encoders and i'm wondering if i can combine it with odometry provided from laser_scan_matcher since the robot have a hokuyo laser sensor ?  and by the way what do you think it's better to get odometry from laser scan  between laser_scan matcher and hector_slam ?

thanks  in advance for your answer .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295616/get-odometry-from-hector_slam/) by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 58 on 2018-06-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-06-28**:
https://answers.ros.org/question/104971/using-hector-slam-with-amcl-for-localization-in-a-pre-made-map/

**Comment by [chrissunny94](https://answers.ros.org/users/33207/chrissunny94/) on 2018-06-28**:
You can use [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) to fuse the odometries

**Comment by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) on 2018-06-29**:
thanks for answering , i think i should use hector_slam but it's hard to find the right parameter  in the launch file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@chrissunny94  thank you i found the solution [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/104966/using-hector-mapping-for-odometry-with-amcl-for-localization-in-a-pre-given-map/)

---

Originally posted by [kesuke](https://answers.ros.org/users/34267/kesuke/) with karma: 58 on 2018-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0